# How to reduce/combine rows in a dataframe based on specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner and would appreciate some help :)
I want to reduce the amount of rows by combining rows based on a variable.

I have given data set:

```
d = {
   'day': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three'], 
   'switch': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ],
   'value': ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

    day     switch  value
0   one     0       green
1   one     1       red
2   two     0       blue
3   three   1       orange
4   three   0       purple
```

I try to restructure the data set to look like this:

```
    day      switch_0_value    switch_1_value
0   one      green             red
1   two      blue              NAN
2   three    purple            orange
```

I have looked at 'combine_first' but don't know how to apply that within a loop.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922051/pandas-dataframe-convert-time-series-with-multiple-elements-to-a-flattened-da/61928523#61928523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
result = df[df["switch"] == 0][["day", "value"]].rename(columns = {"value":"switch_0_value"})
result = pd.merge(result, df[df["switch"] == 1][["day", "value"]], how='left').rename(columns = {"value":"switch_1_value"})
result
    day    switch_0_value   switch_1_value
0   one    green            red
1   two    blue             NaN
2   three  purple           orange
```

Comment: Hey Let's try,
this was a great help! Thank you for helping me out and introducing me to a new approach. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`df.unstack`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) here.

```
df.set_index(['day','switch']).value.unstack(-1)

switch       0       1
day
one      green     red
three   purple  orange
two       blue     NaN
```

Or [**`df.pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df.pivot(index='day',columns='switch',values='value')

switch       0       1
day
one      green     red
three   purple  orange
two       blue     NaN
```

or using [**`df.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg) and [`pd.NamedAgg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html?highlight=namedagg#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) is just for adding custom named columns

```
df.groupby('day').agg(switch_0=pd.NamedAgg(column='value',aggfunc='first'),
                      switch_1=pd.NamedAgg(column='value',aggfunc=lambda x:x.iloc[-1] 
                      if x.size>1 else np.nan))

      switch_0 switch_1
day
one      green      red
three   orange   purple
two       blue      NaN
```

or using [**`df.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) but `pivot_table`'s default `aggfunc` is `'mean'` so we need to get little dirty here. ;)

```
df.pivot_table(index='day',columns='switch',values='value',aggfunc=lambda x:x)
switch       0       1
day
one      green     red
three   purple  orange
two       blue     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you Ch3steR for your help. I struggled a bit with the double index. Still, getting to know the unstack() function was interesting.
Much appreciated you sacrificing some of your time to help me out! :)

Comment: @DanaMiles Glad to this answer helped. I left links to the relevant documentation pages, they have some examples to better understand what does the function do, else there's always an answer in SO regarding pretty much everything. ;)

Comment: Thank you! SO is a great place :)

Answer (score 0):

To have the proper ordering of days, start from conversion of *day*
column from plain *string* to *Categorical*:

```
days = ['one', 'two', 'three']
dayCat = pd.Categorical(days, categories=days, ordered=True)
df.day = df.day.astype(dayCat)
```

Then compute the result:

```
result = df.groupby('day').apply(lambda grp: grp.sort_values('switch')
    .value.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().add_prefix('switch_')\
    .add_suffix('_value').reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
     day switch_0_value switch_1_value
0    one          green            red
1    two           blue            NaN
2  three         purple         orange
```

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo,
thanks for the suggestion! I'll give it a shot and will apply it to my real data set :)